# How do I make use of a parameter in a ElapsedEventHandler (Timer)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, timer

```
List<System.Timers.Timer> myTimers = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();
    
private void startFunction()
{    
    for (var parameter = 0; parameter < list.Count; parameter++)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds);

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(someFunction);
        timer.Start();
        myTimers.Add(timer);
    }
}

// without the int parameter this code works 
public void someFunction(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, int parameter) 
{
    // some code that have to run over time
}
```

So on the *someFunction* method I used a *parameter (int)* and without it, this is working out fine. I just want to send a parameter through this function and with searching online and trying different methods it still does not work.

Anyone having knowledge on how to send a parameter using the function *someFunction* every 10 minutes?

Comment: you can't, the event simply has only the eventargs available. How would you imagine the timer to infer the value for that parameter - it has no clue that param even exists. How is that param populated? Where do you set it and where do you use it? I suppose it has nothing to do with the timer at all.

Comment: Where does the value of this parameter come from?

Comment: I left that out because I didn't want to write to much code in this example to be more clarified but it seems to be mistake

Comment: In that case, just do `timer.Elasped += (o, e) => someFunction(o, e, parameter);`. The lambda you supply to `Elapsed` captures the variable `parameter`, and will then pass it to `someFunction` when it's invoked

Comment: better way could be encapsule the timer and your parameter as some class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `parameter` is just a local variable, you can create a lambda which captures this variable, and passes it to your `someFunction` method.

```
private void startFunction()
{    
    for (var parameter = 0; parameter < list.Count; parameter++)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((10)).TotalMilliseconds);

        int parameterCopy = parameter;
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => someFunction(o, e, parameterCopy);
        timer.Start();
        myTimers.Add(timer);
    }
}
```

The `parameterCopy` is required because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp).

Comment: This sadly didn't work out for me

Comment: @Ando Why not? It probably means that there's critical information missing from your question, but we need to understand what that is before we can help

Comment: maybe the important information can be that the code above someFunction is also in their own function. And that int parameter is from a list.Count and have to be different for every item in that list..

Comment: @Ando Well it's a simple local variable in your question, and there's no "also in their own function", so could you fix your question please? I answered the question as asked

Comment: @Ando Thanks. It's currently not valid C# however -- it's not possible to nest a `public void` method inside another method. Can you make sure your question actually contains your real code please?

Comment: minor mistakes while editing

Comment: @Ando Right, but nested functions in C# *are* a thing, so it's not clear whether the mistake is the nesting, or the presence of the `public`

Comment: @Ando See my edit

Comment: excuse me, I did another test and your method seems to work indeed! thank you!